# Is the Angular2 Material components compatible with older version?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

For Example.
While I'm using Angular2 Material version 5.0.0-rc0.

After A few days, the 5.0.0-rc1 is already released and fixed bugs that I need.

Can I Use

`npm install --save @angular/material@latest @angular/cdk@latest`

to upgrade the component or it will cause any problems?

Comment: Use version control like git and just test it. You can revert to a previous commit if you run in to issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you should check the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for every new release. If there are any breaking changes, it should be listed in the changelog under the release.

For now ([`5.0.0-rc.1`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#5.0.0-rc.1%20felt-photon)), there's doesn't appear to be any breaking changes present, so you can safely upgrade your dependencies.